# HTC Desire S on Android Marketplace - "the requested item could not be found"

Tags: applications, google-play-store, downloading

I cannot download, not update apps. I get the above mentioned message.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know "The requested item could not be found" status comes when the particular app/game is not compatible with your android mobile or its not there in  Market. I don't know if there are any other scenarios the same will occur.

Comment: Not really. Is Skype not compatible with my Android device? Today i somehow installed it successfully.

Comment: Because I got the same issue more than couple of times. And I rechecked that and found that thats happening because its not compatible with my mobile and not available in Market.

Comment: @Boris_yo Skype is compatible with very few phones and disallowed on many carriers.